# stackLabels configuration in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working with highcharts and having some problems with `stackLabels` configuration of highcharts. I was asked to display a bar chart with "score/full score" format, e.g. 6 out of 10 should be like

⬛︎⬛︎⬛︎⬛︎⬛︎⬛︎⬜︎⬜︎⬜︎⬜︎ 6/10

And I faked it with [stacked bar](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-stacked) chart with 6 for the first part of the bar and 4 for the second part.

**[Solved]** However, I don't know how to display `6/10` in `stackLabels` (It seems that I can only use `{total}` in it, while I can use `{point.y}/{point.fullscore}` in `dataLabels`).

**[Unsolved]** And also, when I use the basic bar chart, `dataLabels` automatically adjust its position (In my case, `dataLabels` will show on the left of the right edge of the bar). However, **how should I force the `stackLabels` to display?**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21194146/4158282) points out that there is no enough space for `stackLabels` to display, and the solution is to make `max` value bigger and leave some space for it. However, the solution is not that elegant to me, and also since my bar chart is horizontal and the label should be long.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer second question:

You can set `yAxis.stackLabels.crop` to false, so labels will be rendered always. Those labels won't show up inside the plotting area, but will be rendered somewhere outside. `stackLabels` are not `dataLabels` - `dataLabels` have option `justify`, which forces labels to be rendered inside the plotting area.

However, in Highcharts you can get access to those labels, and move them (that's why `crop` needs to be set to `false` - to render labels anyway), here is simple POC:

```
function updateStacks() {
  var chart = this,
    H = Highcharts,
    padding = 15,
    item,
    bbox;

  for (var stackName in chart.yAxis[0].stacks) {
    for (var itemName in chart.yAxis[0].stacks[stackName]) {
      item = chart.yAxis[0].stacks[stackName][itemName]; // get stack item
      bbox = item.label.getBBox(true); // get label's bounding box

      // if label is outside, translate it:
      if (bbox.width + bbox.x > chart.plotWidth) {
        // add some poding, for a better look&feel:
        item.label.translate(-bbox.width - padding);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now simply use that method in `load` and `redraw` events, here you are:

```
chart: {
  type: 'bar',
  events: {
    redraw: updateStacks,
    load: updateStacks
  }
},
```

And live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/awe4abwk/ - let me know if something is not clear.

PS: Your answer with `formatter` for `stackLabels` is good!

Comment: Thx! Sorry for replying so late! Though I don't need it in work right now but it works as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Use formatter to change default stack label. You can access axis label with this.axis.

```
stackLabels: {

    enabled: true,
    formatter: function() {
        return (this.axis.series[1].yData[this.x] / this.total * 100).toPrecision(2) + '%';
       //Make your changes here to reflect your output. This is just a sample code
    }
}
```

Now to always show stack labels you have two options which are described here.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190252/highcharts-stack-totals-on-top-for-percent-stacking)

Comment: Yep! I've found the same solution! Thanks a lot!

Comment: However, about the second question, the answer points out that the `stackLabels` is working but there is no enough space for it to display. I know that, but when there is no room for `dataLabels`, it will adjust its position automatically, in this case, it will show on the left of the edge of the bar.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've found the solution for **the first question: How to show the specific series values in `stackLabels`?** from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14536955/4158282).

In my case, the code should be:

```
yAxis: {
  stackLabels: {
    formatter: function() {
      return [this.axis.series[1].yData[this.x], '/', this.total].join('');
    },
    enabled: true,
  }
}
```

If you have better solution, post it! And I still have no idea about how to find it in the [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts), maybe I should dig more...